# What is grub2 default font?

Tags: grub2, fonts, default

what is ubuntu 12.04 grub2 default font? I changed it and don't know what it was to change it back. I have tried many different font and style to no avail.

Comment: How did you change it?

Comment: with grub customizer

Answer (score 10):

The default font of grub2 in 12.04 is `unicode.pf2`. Check this command

```
grep -n font /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

It is described in 45th line in `grub.cfg` file. The location of the font is `/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2`.

- Check [this related question on Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/31672/19288)

#### Update to include information from OP's comment:

OP wrote in a later comment,

> In Grub Customizer on the right side there is a little red minus sign that removes the custom font. click that and hit save and boom back to the default font

Comment: Thanks for the help. I feel sheepish. I Grub Customizer on the right side there is a little red minus sign that removes the custom font. click that and hit save and boom back to the default font.

Comment: And how would I find that in a font picker? I can't find any font named "unicode.pf2"

Answer (score 1):

The default grub font is not listed in the options of Grub Customizer.

But you can revert the changes you made by clicking the red "minus" button that is next to the font selection option in Grub Customizer.

Answer (score 1):

Install the unifont like so:

```
$ sudo apt install unifont
```

Choose from the list by searching "uni"

Answer (score -3):

I believe the default grub2 font is Ariel

Comment: I'm sure grub2's font isn't Ariel. Arial only get installed if you install *msttfcorefonts-installer* package.

Comment: I know it is not. I have ready tried that.

Comment: my mistake! Sorry!

Comment: The font isn't a mermaid - it's called "Arial", not "Ariel"! XD